# How do I make these layers not overlap?

Tags: jquery, html, css

http://removed.com/jquery/test.html#

I have three problems that I need help with.

1 ) When you click "More" on top right, it open a div `#search` and the background is being overlapped by the brown element below. I tried using z-index, but it didn't work.

2 ) I'm trying to make the div `#search` align directly beneath the "More", but upon setting the width of `#search`, it aligns to the left side.

3 ) When I hover over the navigation on the left, the popup is being overlapped by the text in the middle. I want the popup to be on top of the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving the `position:relative` to element with id `#search` and set its `z-index` to a greater value such as 100